# Switching to SQL Server 2012 with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

Does anyone of you have any experience with switching from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012 with Entity Framework?

How do I accomplish that? Do I only need to change the ConnectionString in the app.config or will I face any difficulties?

Comment: Why should I risk to break anything when I have the ability to ask experienced users who maybe can give hints of things which can break?

Comment: If you test it locally, nothing can go wrong ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the connection string :) and it will work. Had no problem with it at work

Comment: Thanks, thought that Microsoft maintains backwards-compatibility but wasn't really sure. There's not something I should take care off, such as rebuilding the Database model?

Comment: I had no problems whatsoever and I suspect you won't either unless you are doing something very exotic. If you experience a problem you can put the database in 2008 compatibility mode (that's done by default AFAIK) . Also, if it's not in place, strive to have a staging/preprod environment where you can test this.

Comment: How about undergrating from 2012 to 2008? I tried it but it thows exception.